# i want to collect the current time of a video

Tags: python

I found a way to extract a frame from a video, using cv2.
but What i also want to achieve is: (press pause -while the video is playing- so the frame is captured and **the current time of the video is taken**, So I can make a comment or whatever)
my code for extracting the frame

```
import cv2

vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('d:/final.mp4')
vidcap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC,25505)      # just cue to 20 sec. position
success,image = vidcap.read()
if success:
    cv2.imwrite("frame22sec.jpg", image)     # save frame as JPEG file
    cv2.imshow("20sec",image)
    cv2.waitKey()
```

I failed in my research (8 hours), please direct me to a proper method
I am using python34

Comment: Maybe you can get the framerate https://www.learnopencv.com/how-to-find-frame-rate-or-frames-per-second-fps-in-opencv-python-cpp/ from the video and using your known frame position calculate the time.

Comment: how can i know my frame position??

Comment: Have a look at all the properties here: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-get

Comment: i have been looking and found that CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC is what i need, but I couldn't apply it, because i want to pull the frame position dynamically from the video,